# Translating Insert into Select to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this sql query that i want to translate to entity Framework

i need to insert more than one row in one run in entity like what this query do

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbllistDepartment
(
    department_sys_id,
    department,
    status,
    client_sys_id,
    lang_sys_id
)
SELECT @siDepartmentSysId,@siDepartment, @iiStatus, 
       @siClientSysId,  lang_sys_id
  FROM tblLanguageSettings 
  WHERE lang_sys_id <> 'Admin001'
```

i have tried this but its inserting just one row

```
public static void Insert(string langSysId, string clientSysId,string name, int status)
    {
        Crs2Model context = new Crs2Model();
        string SysId = MyLibrary.StringCreator.GetSysId();

        tblListDepartment deptObj = new tblListDepartment()
        {
            department_sys_id = SysId,
            client_sys_id = clientSysId,
            lang_sys_id=langSysId,
            department=name,
            status=status
        };

        context.tblListDepartments.Add(deptObj);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Show your DBContext name, my friend.

Comment: My question has been updated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first, you need filter data from tbllistDepartment table. And then loop through this data.
Here is a sample. You can refer, my friend:

```
using (DBContext ctx = new DBContext())
{     

  var department = ctx.tbllistDepartment.Where(c => c.lang_sys_id != "Admin001");   

    foreach(var item in department)
{
      var obj = new tbllistDepartment()
      {
         department_sys_id = item.department_sys_id,
         department = item.department,
         status = item.status,
         client_sys_id = item.client_sys_id,
         lang_sys_id = item.lang_sys_id
      }
      ctx.tbllistDepartment.Add(obj);
}   

  // Insert into the database.
  ctx.SaveChanges();                        
}
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend that's solved my problem ... wish i had 15 reputations so i can vote you up :)

Comment: @AhmadA.Al-Dwairi: Yeah, so happy to help you, my friend :))

Comment: @AhmadA.Al-Dwairi: Thank you, my friend. You kept the promise, vote me up :)). But I don't know why anyone downvotes my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add on your class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

You can use the command

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand (sqlcommand,[parameters]);
```

And these are the following commands:

```
string sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbllistDepartment (department_sys_id,department,status,client_sys_id,lang_sys_id) SELECT {0},{1},{2}, {3},{4} FROM tblLanguageSettings WHERE lang_sys_id <> {5}";    
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand, @siDepartmentSysId,@siDepartment,@iiStatus, @siClientSysId, lang_sys_id,'Admin001');
```

Comment: so, it's not possible to do this with just Linq then I take it?

Comment: This is dangerous if your table changes.  Normally you would get a compilation error after updating a table.